# App crashes when text in edit text changes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set text to an edittext field by using edittext1 minus edittext2.

edittext3 = edittext1 - edittext2

However when i remove an integer from edittext2, it crashes.

Eg. by removing the  "0" from "80" the app crashes even though the is "8" left on the edit text.

Any help or suggestion?

```
eactualQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //ebalance.setText((Integer.valueOf(emaximumQuantity.getText().toString())-Integer.valueOf(eactualQuantity.getText().toString())));
            if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
                String a = emaximumQuantity.getText().toString();
                int aint = Integer.parseInt(a);
                String b = eactualQuantity.getText().toString();
                int bint = Integer.parseInt(b);


                int c = (aint - bint);

                ebalance.setText(c);
            }


        }
    });
```

Below is the logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: nsl.nsl_material_movement, PID: 11195
>                                                                              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc0
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
>                                                                                  at nsl.nsl_material_movement.UpdateActivity$1.afterTextChanged(UpdateActivity.java:123)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9375)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
>                                                                                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1262)
>                                                                                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:574)
>                                                                                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:229)
>                                                                                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:227)
>                                                                                  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:370)
>                                                                                  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:71)
>                                                                                  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:479)
>                                                                                  at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7316)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7093)
>                                                                                  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2688)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11658)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:437)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1818)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3252)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:540)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:317)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:351)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4714)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4307)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4468)
>                                                                                  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
>                                                                                  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
>   01-21 16:52:12.129 11195-11195/nsl.nsl_material_movement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
>                                                                                  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
>                                                                                  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: `ebalance.setText(c);` - You can't call `setText()` with an arbitrary `int`. Convert it to a `String` first; e.g., `ebalance.setText(String.valueOf(c));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an int to a textview. It must be a string like this

```
ebalance.setText(Integer.toString(c));
```